# groovy - is there any implicit variable to get access to item index in "each" method

Tags: groovy

Is there any way to remove variable "i" in the following example and still get access to index of item that being printed  ?

```
def i = 0;
"one two three".split().each  {
    println ("item [ ${i++} ] = ${it}");
}
```

=============== EDIT ================

I found that one possible solution is to use "eachWithIndex" method:

```
"one two three".split().eachWithIndex  {it, i
    println ("item [ ${i} ] = ${it}");
}
```

Please do let me know if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `eachWithIndex()`

```
"one two three four".split().eachWithIndex() { entry, index ->
      println "${index} : ${entry}" }
```

this will result in

```
0 : one
1 : two
2 : three
3 : four
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what 'other solutions' you are looking for...  The only other thing you can do that I can think of (with Groovy 1.8.6), is something like:

```
"one two three".split().with { words ->
  [words,0..<words.size()].transpose().collect { word, index ->
    word * index
  }
}
```

As you can see, this allows you to use `collect` with an index as well (as there is no `collectWithIndex` method).

Comment: @loteq That's basically what I said...  After getting it right, the OP asks for _"other solutions"_ for some reason.  Also, if you want to use an index in `collect`, `find`, it's the only way other than an external var...

Comment: Cool answer, but the use of `with` hinders the readability of this solution IMO. I linked your answer in mine, which generalizes this in an `enumerate` method =D

Comment: @epidemian Yeah, my thoughts on the `with` was to avoid adding a local var in a question about avoiding local vars ;-) Ahhhhh, like off the [mailing list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Traversing-collections-with-indexes-td5670914.html)?

Comment: @tim_yates Oh, so that's why this question (and my answer) felt like a deja-vu :). I'm not subscribed to the mailing list (probably subscribing now) but i knew about the [Jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3797), in fact i was the one who proposed the enumerate and the Map type conversion there :) (BTW, in retrospective, returning a Map from enumerate seems like a more natural approach than what i answered here, IDK why i forgot about that). I really like ataylor's iterator-based implementation of enumerate though =D

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you want to use the index of the collection on other methods than `each` is to define an `enumerate` method that returns pairs `[index, element]`, analog to [Python's enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
Iterable.metaClass.enumerate = { start = 0 -> 
    def index = start
    delegate.collect { [index++, it] }
}
```

So, for example:

```
assert 'un dos tres'.tokenize().enumerate() == [[0,'un'], [1,'dos'], [2,'tres']]
```

(notice that i'm using `tokenize` instead of `split` because the former returns an Iterable, while the later returns a `String[]`)

And we can use this new collection with `each`, as you wanted:

```
'one two three'.tokenize().enumerate().each { index, word ->
    println "$index: $word"
}
```

Or we can use it with other iteration methods :D

```
def repetitions = 'one two three'.tokenize().enumerate(1).collect { n, word -> 
    ([word] * n).join(' ')
}
assert repetitions == ['one', 'two two', 'three three three']
```

---

**Note**: Another way of defining the `enumerate` method, following tim_yates' [more functional approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380637/581845) is:

```
Iterable.metaClass.enumerate = { start = 0 -> 
    def end = start + delegate.size() - 1
    [start..end, delegate].transpose()
}
```